# Trouble adding maps on mapfishapp

Tags: georchestra

I am using GeoOrchestra 13.09, i can add and show the maps that are on geoserver but when i try to add a map in the mapfishapp tool using a .shp file the error that displays on the log is the next

2014-09-15 18:46:17 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] DispatcherServlet with name 'ws' processing POST request for [/mapfishapp-private/ws/togeojson/]
2014-09-15 18:46:17 CommonsMultipartResolver [DEBUG] Found multipart file [geofile] of size 1164 bytes with original filename [aerodromos.shp], stored in memory
2014-09-15 18:46:17 DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Matching patterns for request [/togeojson/] are [/togeojson/*/, /togeojson/*]
2014-09-15 18:46:17 DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping [DEBUG] URI Template variables for request [/togeojson/] are {}
2014-09-15 18:46:17 DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping [DEBUG] Mapping [/togeojson/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.georchestra.mapfishapp.ws.UpLoadGeoFileController@6d61968] and 1 interceptor
2014-09-15 18:46:17 HandlerMethodInvoker [DEBUG] Invoking request handler method: public void rg.georchestra.mapfishapp.ws.UpLoadGeoFileController.toGeoJson(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.io.IOException
2014-09-15 18:46:17 ws [DEBUG] RESPONSE:{"success":false, "error":"fileupload_error_unsupportedFormat", "msg": "unsupported file type"}
2014-09-15 18:46:17 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'ws': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2014-09-15 18:46:17 CommonsMultipartResolver [DEBUG] Cleaning up multipart file [geofile] with original filename [aerodromos.shp], stored in memory
2014-09-15 18:46:17 DispatcherServlet [DEBUG] Successfully completed request

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Did you upload a zipped shapefile or just the .shp file ?
Zipped shapefile is the way to go.